# How to find number of days between each status change

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have the following table named Application in Postgres:

```
ID    JA_ID    TO_STATUS      FROM_STATUS      DATE
1      100     Matched        NULL             2019-05-06
2      100     INterview      Matched          2019-05-30
3      100     Extended       INterview        2019-05-31
4      200     New_Applicant  NULL             2020-04-01
5      200     INterview      New_applicant    2020-04-05
6      200     Rejected       interview        2020-05-10
```

Now I need to calculate # of days between each status change for every JA_ID from this table.I have sorted the status change based JA_ID and DAte(in asc). My O/P **'DAYS'** column should be like this:

```
ID    JA_ID    TO_STATUS      FROM_STATUS      DATE           DAYS
1      100     Matched        NULL             2019-05-06     NULL
2      100     Interview      Matched          2019-05-30     24
3      100     Extended       INterview        2019-05-31.    1
4      200     New_Applicant  NULL             2020-04-01.    NULL
5      200     Interview      New_applicant    2020-04-05.    4
6      200     Rejected       interview        2020-05-10.    5
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming "date" is defined with the datatype `date` (as it should be), you can use `lag()` to get the previous date and subtract the values:

```
select id, ja_id, to_status, from_status, "date", 
       "date" - lag("date") over (partition by ja_id order by "date") as days
from application;
```